# PrimeNG table not shown on the browser

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a **PrimeNG** table in **TablePrimeNgComponent**.

**table-prime-ng.component.html :**

```
<p-table [value]="cars">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Vin</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Color</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-car>
        <tr>
            <td>{{car.vin}}</td>
            <td>{{car.year}}</td>
            <td>{{car.brand}}</td>
            <td>{{car.color}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
```

**TablePrimeNgComponent:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CarService } from '../car.service';


export interface Car {vin; year; brand; color;}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-prime-ng',
  templateUrl: './table-prime-ng.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-prime-ng.component.css']
})
export class TablePrimeNgComponent implements OnInit {

  cars : Car[];

  constructor(private carservice: CarService) { }

  ngOnInit() {this.cars = this.carservice.getCars();}

}
```

**CarService** is created and successfully returns the car array. I can show the returned data. **PrimeNG** is also installed.
When I compile and run the program, I do not get any errors. At the same time, the tables doe not render anything to the browser.
Can you help me finding out what the problem is?

Comment: can you post the value of console.log(JSON.stringify(this.cars));

Comment: Yes. I can get them on the console.

Comment: post it here with the question

Comment: Here is the output to the console:
[{"vin":"dsad231ff","year":2012,"brand":"VW","color":"Orange"},{"vin":"gwregre345","year":2011,"brand":"Audi","color":"Black"}]

My question is why this does not render to the template.

Comment: Check answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use  **`<p-column>`**

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars">
  <p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
  <p-column field="year"  header="Year">    </p-column>
  <p-column field="color" header="Color"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-turbo-table-ekhmmc?file=app%2Fdata-table%2Fdata-table.component.html)**

**EDIT :**

With ng-template also it works well, make sure you declared cols in the template,

```
 export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {
  cars: Array<any> = [{"vin":"dsad231ff","year":2012,"brand":"VW","color":"Orange"},{"vin":"gwregre345","year":2011,"brand":"Audi","color":"Black"}];
 cols: any[];
  constructor() { 
    this.cols = [
            { field: 'vin', header: 'Vin' },
            { field: 'year', header: 'Year' },
            { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand' },
            { field: 'color', header: 'Color' }
        ];
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**[`DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-turbo-table-ymkqkn?file=app%2Fdata-table%2Fdata-table.component.ts)**

Comment: Thank you. But I still prefer to do it with ng-template and tr/th/td. The question is actually a part of PrimeNG tutorial: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table  .  So it is the code that should work, but I cannot get it work. That is what I need to figure out.

Comment: Check the above demo

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. By reading your code I found out that I had missed importing TableModule . This works fine now.

Comment: The demo link of stackblitz shared above is not working. Can you please share the updated link?

Comment: Both demos have been removed from Stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

As both the demo links are broken and I ran into same issue and figured out the solution based on the comments. So, just posting an updated answer in case someone is looking for an answer which is easier to find.

Most certainly you have missed out on importing the table module in your app module.

```
import {TableModule} from 'primeng/table';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    TableModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: []
})
```

One can refer to the official [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablebasic-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) for more details.